# Realm "Cannot create asynchronous query" while using multiple addChangeListeners

Tags: android, realm

I'm getting this type of error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsResults.cpp line 252
       at io.realm.internal.OsResults.nativeStartListening(OsResults.java)
       at io.realm.internal.OsResults.addListener(OsResults.java:405)
       at io.realm.internal.OsResults.addListener(OsResults.java:412)
       at io.realm.RealmResults.addChangeListener(RealmResults.java:173)
       at io.realm.internal.ObservableCollection$RealmChangeListenerWrapper.onChange(ObservableCollection.java:39)
       at io.realm.internal.ObservableCollection$CollectionObserverPair.onChange(ObservableCollection.java:20)
       at io.realm.internal.ObservableCollection$Callback.onCalled(ObservableCollection.java:64)
       at io.realm.internal.ObservableCollection$Callback.onCalled(ObservableCollection.java:54)
       at io.realm.internal.ObserverPairList.foreach(ObserverPairList.java:109)
       at io.realm.internal.OsResults.notifyChangeListeners(OsResults.java:451)
       at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeBeginTransaction(OsSharedRealm.java)
       at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.beginTransaction(OsSharedRealm.java:269)
       at io.realm.BaseRealm.beginTransaction(BaseRealm.java:401)
       at io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction(Realm.java:146)
```

How can I make sure that I'm not in transaction while I am adding addChangeListeners? A simple approach of `mRealm.isInTransaction` could help or the problem is in codes structure?

```
public void update() {
    sData = dataQuery.sort(Data.ORDER, Sort.ASCENDING).findAllAsync();
    sData.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Data> element) {
            sDiffData = mRealm.where(DiffData.class)
                    .greaterThanOrEqualTo(...)
                    .lessThan(...)
                    .equalTo(..)
                    .findAllAsync();
            sDiffData.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<...>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(RealmResults<...> element) {
                    ...
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I cannot re-produce error myself, but I can see it in crashlytics showing up pretty often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if you have a **UI-thread write transaction** and also have a `RealmChangeListener` in which you also execute an async query (or `addChangeListener`).

Solution 1: don't use UI thread write transactions because they can potentially block your UI and your app will be slow and bad

Solution 2: if you're in a write transaction inside the RealmChangeListener, then execute the logic in a `handler.post {` block

```
private void fetchDiff() {
        sDiffData = mRealm.where(DiffData.class)
                .greaterThanOrEqualTo(...)
                .lessThan(...)
                .equalTo(..)
                .findAllAsync();
        sDiffData.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<...>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<...> element) {
                ...
        });
}

public void update() {
    sData = dataQuery.sort(Data.ORDER, Sort.ASCENDING).findAllAsync();
    sData.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Data> element) {
            Realm realm = element.getRealm();
            if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
                handler.post(() -> {
                    fetchDiff();
                });
            } else {
                fetchDiff();
            }
        }
    });
}
```