# How to handle states with redux and realm [react-natve]

Tags: mongodb, react-native, react-redux, realm

I'm working on a complex application using react-native, and I'm struggling on how to manage states and persist-states.
I'd like to achieve something like instagram, loading posts one time in redux and then save a bit of them in local-memory, to show something when the user open the app without internet connection.

Now to handle states across the app I'm using react-redux even if it cause some lag on react-navigation transition, and to save data locally suggest me to use redux-persist for low-complexity apps and realm for medium/hight-complexity apps.

- What's exactly the practical difference between redux and realm?
  (excluding the fact that the former doesn't persist when app is closed).
- Is it right to use both redux and realm? If so what's the best implementation?

Thank you.
Please no useless question, I've been clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also working on messaging app (consider complex app?) and here is my answer to your question.

1. Redux is `state management` library and Realm is just `database` solution. I guess you are trying to say [redux persist/asyncstorage](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). `redux persist` allows you to store key-pair value in your app while `realm` is way more efficient when storing large amount of data.
2. Yes, it is right to use redux and realm together. **Redux** is used as `state` management, managing all the UI state, while **Realm** is served as database to store your data.

Example (Messaging App)

1. When load messages from API, store it in `realm` directly.
2. Add a listener for `realm`, listen the data changes and expose them in `redux` state.
3. You may **whitelist/blacklist** your state in `redux persist` by destroy these state when you killed the application.

Here is my small explanation.

Comment: Therefore, following your example, Once get messages from database I store them directly in realm and in redux too, so if the user, for example, modify a message I update the changes using redux and then realm? Why redux is still necessary in this example? If I update states directly in Realm and the update the changes on my web-db, isn't enough? Thank you

Comment: for my case, I was updating my UI through `redux`. So `redux` is something like a middleware to communicate between UI and `realm`. When you modify a message, `realm` expose a listener and from that listener you can directly update the `redux` and reflect in UI.

Comment: Ok thank you, sounds good the word middleware for redux.

Comment: Also writing a messaging app and finding that realm listeners are pretty fragile when creating them while trying to handle incoming changes. See:
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/error-cannot-create-asynchronous-query-while-in-a-write-transaction/113270
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277341/realm-cannot-create-asynchronous-query-while-using-multiple-addchangelisteners
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5771
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/4306

I'm going to try and use redux for local state and realm for data storage only.